# JSF application with JPA only

Tags: design-patterns, jpa, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to design user administration module using JPA and JSF only without EJB. I get **java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl** I have usercontroller with following code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class UserController implements Serializable {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em;
    EntityTransaction tx;
    private List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    private List<Groups> groups = new ArrayList<Groups>();
    Groups group = new Groups();
    Users user = new Users();
    public String[] usergroups;
    boolean editGroup = false;
        boolean addGroup = false;
        boolean editUser = false;
        boolean addUser = false;

//getter and setter
}
```

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(/*catalog = "GIS",*/ schema = "useradministration")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserid", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = :userid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserpassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userpassword = :userpassword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByMiddlename", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.middlename = :middlename"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLastname", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.lastname = :lastname")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
     @SequenceGenerator(name="useradministration.users_userid_seq",
                       sequenceName="useradministration.users_userid_seq",
                       allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator="useradministration.users_userid_seq")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer userid;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(length = 200)
    private String userpassword;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String firstname;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String middlename;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String lastname;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Groups> groupsList;
```

}

**Group Entity:**

```
package com.ncell.user;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author suamatya
 */
@Entity
@Table(schema = "useradministration")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findByGroupid", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.groupid = :groupid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findByGroupname", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.groupname = :groupname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findByGroupdesc", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.groupdesc = :groupdesc")})
public class Groups implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="useradministration.groups_groupid_seq",
                       sequenceName="useradministration.groups_groupid_seq",
                       allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator="useradministration.groups_groupid_seq")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer groupid;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String groupname;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(length = 200)
    private String groupdesc;
    @JoinTable(name = "useradministration.usergroups", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "groupid", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "userid", nullable = false)})
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Users> usersList;
}
```

So the question is : Is there any  example with JPA and JSF only without EJB? I have made the controller serializable because it's view scoped.

Answer (score 1):

I never use EJBs and it just works for me. Not sure what's causing your specific error. However, you might want to reconsider having the EntityManagerFactory in your Bean imo.

I would instead create the factory once only in a class like this:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
```

Then I would depedency inject that `@ApplicationScoped` bean in a BaseBean that can be extended by every other bean. The baseBean creates the entityManager from the factory and you simply use getEntityManager() in the actual Bean for example UserController.

The exception is strange, maybe post the whole stacktrace because the EntityManager is not Serializable, its a known limitation...

Comment: Never used jpa so could you please provide me with example?

Comment: I don't use managed beans from JSF so i'm a little short on examples on that.

JSF managed beans are not commonly seen as good practice anymore in favor for the much better CDI beans.

A great, great startup example for that is this: https://github.com/struberg/lightweightEE

Imo this project of yours are missing the cornerstone CDI and possibly maven too. Research those techs and go for the example I provided (imo).

That said a little more googling should be fruitful, it's a common combo.

Comment: Won't I have problem with CDI bean? There is no alternative for viewscoped bean in CDI.

Comment: Use JSF 2.2 and CDI 1.1 and you are golden ;) That exacat problem was solved in EE7.

Alternative to that is to use @ViewAccessScoped from myfaces CODI because I think it's still not implemented in it's successor deltaspike.